# AutoHotKey two keys for one

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to know how to script so that two keys pressed and held in a specific order will press another key.  To be specific I'd like to press tab and then q and receive the output of F1.

Comment: Is your F1 key broken? i'm not sure about scripting something like this but there is a built in on board keyboard, if you found the code for that output through that you could probably script it so you can run it from a .bat file, or hotkey it so tab - q runs the bat file.

Comment: I also wonder why you just don't press F1.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old function of AutoHotkey and documented here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Features

If you want the sequence q & Tab to do press F1, you can script it like this:

```
q & tab::Send {F1} ; when q and tab are pressed in that order, F1 is pressed
```

Note that q will not work anymore, either by itself, or in other keyboard shortcuts if you don't add them here (Ctrl-q, Ctrl-Shift-q etc). I therefore don't recommend using a single letter as a prefix. In fact, I recommend pressing F1 if you want F1.

```
q::q ; You need this code for q to keep its function as q
+q::Q ; ; You need this code for Q to keep its function as Q
```

Comment: The key repeating doesn't work anymore after this remap, do you have any idea to fix it?